# Joi validation with dollar sign in the number text

Tags: joi

Is it possible to extend joi to allow for a '$' in the number() validation?

My input is a string like "$12.34".  When I attempt to validate this using Joi.number() I receive an error "{Field} must be a number".  All I need is to remove the $ and it works fine. Is there any way to do this in the schema definition so that I don't have to scrub my incoming data before calling validate?

```
const results = Joi.number().validate("$12.34") // fails
const results = Joi.number().validate("12.34") // succeeds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to extend number with a custom prepare method.

After trying everything I could think of I looked at the source on github and found this [test](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/83092836583a7f4ce16cbf116b8776737e80d16f/test/extend.js#L1417)

```
it('extends number to support comma delimiter', () => {

        const custom = Joi.extend({
            type: 'number',
            base: Joi.number(),
            prepare(value, helpers) {

                if (typeof value !== 'string') {
                    return;
                }

                return { value: value.replace(',', '.') };
            }
        });

        expect(custom.number().validate(2.0)).to.equal({ value: 2.0 });
        expect(custom.number().validate('2.0')).to.equal({ value: 2.0 });
        expect(custom.number().validate('2,0')).to.equal({ value: 2.0 });
        expect(custom.number().validate('2,0', { convert: false }).error).to.be.an.error('"value" must be a number');
        expect(custom.number().validate(undefined).error).to.not.exist();
    });
```

which is basically what I am trying to do so I modified it to fix up '$' instead of ',' and voila

[image: joi_validate_number_with_dollar_sign]

results1 will pass and results2 will error out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with regex then you can use regex to validate the string as follows:

```js
Joi.string().regex(/\$\d+(\.?\d+)?/) 
// \$ check for $ 
// \d+ digit 1 or more
// \.? . one or zero
// (\.?\d+)? match group for 0 or 1 time
```

As input type is string you can be sure that it contains `$` by two ways i.e.

1. replace `$` with empty string.

```js
Joi.number().validate("$12.34".replace("$",""))
```

2. splitting string at `$` and then checking 2nd part (less secure)

```js
Joi.number().validate("$12.34".split("$")[1])
```

Last option is to strip of `$` every-time and then pass remaining part to check if it's number.

Comment: I thought about regex but it means I am testing for a string so I lose the greater/less and other number functions.

Comment: Your input type is string so you have to convert it to number later on and for converting it you need to strip `$` in any way you approach.

Comment: Or you can do string manipulation. Edited answer to add string manipulation method.